# SQL dinámico PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

¿Me pueden ayudar por favor con esta sentencia dinámica que estoy formando? No sé porqué me está generando error:

```
PROCEDURE pr_replica_campo(Un_id_documento              NUMBER,
                           Un_nombre_campo              VARCHAR2,
                           Un_valor_campo               NUMBER,
                           Un_usuario                   VARCHAR2)  
IS
mi_codigo varchar2(500);
BEGIN

mi_codigo :='UPDATE facturas_comerciales dfc
                SET dfc.Un_nombre_campo=Un_valor_campo, '
                 || 'dfc.FE_ACTUALIZACION = ''fecha'', '
                 || 'dfc.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA = ''Un_usuario'' '
                 || 'where dfc.ID_DOCUMENTO =Un_id_documento;';
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_nombre_campo', Un_nombre_campo);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_valor_campo', Un_valor_campo);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'fecha', SYSDATE);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_usuario', Un_usuario);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_id_documento', Un_id_documento);
execute immediate mi_codigo;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN dbms_output.put_line (SQLERRM);

END pr_replica_campo;

PROCEDURE pr_replica_campo(Un_id_documento, Un_nombre_campo,
                           Un_valor_campo, Un_usuario);
```

**Salida del** `dbms_output`:

```
UPDATE cex_det_facturas_comerciales dfc
   SET dfc.ID_MODALIDAD=1, dfc.FE_ACTUALIZACION = '06-DIC-16,
       dfc.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA = '80161170'
 where dfc.ID_DOCUMENTO =12705583;
```

**Error generado:**

> ORA-00911: invalid character

**Tabla**

```
CREATE TABLE facturas_comerciales
(
 ID_DOCUMENTO                    NUMBER(20)    NOT NULL,
 ID_MODALIDAD                    NUMBER(5),  
 ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
 ID_UNIDAD                       NUMBER(5),
 ID_TIPO                         NUMBER(5),
 ID_MODO                         NUMBER(5),
 FE_ACTUALIZACION                DATE
)
```

**Parámetros:**

```
Un_nombre_campo := 'ID_MODALIDAD';
Un_valor_campo := 1,
Un_usuario := '80161170' 
Un_id_documento := 12705583;
```

Comment: Hola, puedes poner una captura de la estructura de la tabla?

Comment: Para entender tu problema, tienes que describir tu tabla `facturas_comerciales` y convertir tu código en un [mcve], porque lo mas probable es que algo está mal con `Un_nombre_campo`, pero sin saber cuales son los valores de tus variables y las columnas de tu tabla, ¿cómo podemos ayudarte? Por otro lado, el diseño de que haces un `update` a una columna dinámica no parece ideal. ¿Alguna razón por hacerlo de esa manera?

Comment: @sakulino, adjunto la estructura de la tabla

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu error. Pudiera proponerte una mejor manera de efectuar el SQL dinámico, pero antes de hacer esto, es mejor entender el problema actual. Por favor, incluye un script más completo que nos sirva de [mcve], y que podamos usar para reproducir tu error específico. El único detalle que yo puedo notar es que no deberías incluir un punto y coma al final de tu SQL dinámico. Pero esto causaría un error diferente.

Comment: @sstan ya modifique la pregunta y envio nuevamente el codigo

Comment: @sstan, ya quedo solucionado le quite la coma al final y funciono...! mil gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repitiendo mi comentario, te sugerí quitar el punto y coma al final de la consulta SQL, que parece que te ayudó. Aunque cuando lo mencioné, el error que tenías era diferente:

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Pero ahora veo que cambiastes el error a:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Y cuando yo ejecuto tu programa, el error que obtengo es:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Es una lástima que parece haber una confusión con el error que en realidad tuvistes, ya que tal vez esto reduzca la utilidad de la pregunta para otras personas en el futuro.

Siempre fue claro que el punto y coma se debían quitar, pero parecía que tenías otro problema, que ahora quedará como un misterio.

**Parametrizar el SQL dinámico**

Aprovecho para recomendar que uses parámetros para la sentencia `UPDATE`. El que uses SQL dinámico no significa que no puedas usar parámetros. Sí se puede, y es buena idea hacerlo para evitar los mismos problemas de siempre: inyección SQL, problemas de comillas, etc.  Y en tu caso específico, te evitaría usar varias llamadas a `replace`, que es un diseño cuestionable.

Pasar parámetros con SQL dinámico se logra usando la cláusula `USING` en la sentencia `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Aquí te dejo el código que puedes usar:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_replica_campo(Un_id_documento NUMBER,
                                             Un_nombre_campo VARCHAR2,
                                             Un_valor_campo NUMBER,
                                             Un_usuario VARCHAR2)  
IS
  mi_codigo varchar2(500);
BEGIN

  mi_codigo := 'UPDATE facturas_comerciales
                   SET ' || Un_nombre_campo || ' = :valor_campo,
                       FE_ACTUALIZACION = SYSDATE,
                       ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA = :usuario
                 WHERE ID_DOCUMENTO = :id_documento';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE mi_codigo
    USING Un_valor_campo, Un_usuario, Un_id_documento;

END pr_replica_campo;
```

Comment: estoy de acuerdo y mil gracias por sus comentarios, pero tengo una duda, si le quisiera añadir con un campo tipo `varchar2`...?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, puede ser un error de las comillas? A veces juegan malas pasadas...

Sino explica mejor qué pretendes hacer.. Te paso el código correjido :) :

```
mi_codigo :='UPDATE facturas_comerciales dfc
                SET dfc.Un_nombre_campo=Un_valor_campo, '
                 || 'dfc.FE_ACTUALIZACION = fecha, '
                 || 'dfc.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA = Un_usuario '
                 || 'where dfc.ID_DOCUMENTO =Un_id_documento';
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_nombre_campo', Un_nombre_campo);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_valor_campo', Un_valor_campo);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'fecha', SYSDATE);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_usuario', Un_usuario);
mi_codigo := replace(mi_codigo, 'Un_id_documento', Un_id_documento);
execute immediate mi_codigo;
```

Entonces necesitas una query más compleja te dejo un enlace para ayudar-te :

http://mundodb.es/pl-sql-dinamico

Pero antes deberías considerar las ventajas y desventajas de las queries dinámicas:

**VENTAJAS:**

-Creación de sentencias en tiempo de ejecución

-Interactivo con el usuario

-Acceder a objetos no existentes en tiempo de compilación

-Gestión de permisos de usuarios de forma dinámica

-Permite ejecutar instrucciones DDL (create, alter, drop, grant, …)

**DESVENTAJAS:**

-No siempre se forman las consultas más optimas

-Problemas de seguridad por ataques de inyección SQL

Comment: Lo que deseo es hacer un query dinámico, para cambiarle el nombre del atributo de la tabla

Comment: la idea es poder pasar como parámetro: el id, el nombre de la columna, el valor, el usuario que actualiza, la idea es poderle pasar el nombre de la columna de manera dinámica.

Answer (score 0):

Se que el comentario es de atrás tiempo, pero justo me estoy topando con problemas así, lo que veo el error es por la concatenación, según yo solo se concatenan las palabras reservadas, comas, paréntesis o si tienes palabras seguidas se puede todo en una, mientras no contenga la variable dinámica, no se bien, pero algo que te puede ayudar para saber si estás construyendo bien tu "sentencia" es: imprime la variable que almacena todo tu update con un dbms_output.put_line(mi_codigo) y así verás si está bien construida.